What does “going off” mean in "Going off the age of the statues"?
What does “going off” mean in the following conversation between A, B, and C? A, B, and C are 3 different speakers.

A: “So that’s the mystery of the statues. A demon?” 
B: “A trap. The
statues were bait.” 
A: “Why?” 
C: “Going off the age of the statues –
could’ve been part of the war with Tevinter.”

I've checked both “Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary” and “The American Heritage Dictionary of The English Language” and couldn't find the right meaning.

This was closed as a dictionary look-up.  Look up “go” or “go off”?  One answer quotes a suitable definition, but this is not what one would most easily find. The “dictionary look-up reason for closing is unhelpful here and wrongly used.

@Xanne, You’re absolutely right. I checked both “Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary” and “The American Heritage Dictionary of The English Language” before posting and neither has the meaning “judging from” for “go off”. I also Googled the phrase and didn’t find the right meaning from the first few results. That’s why I posted the question here. Questions like this always gets closed for the wrong reason: “the OP should check a dictionary first.” How do the mods know he/she didn’t? Did the mods check a dictionary first? Why do they assume a dictionary is exhaustive?

I’ve been studying English for a long time and I find that many colloquialisms are not in the dictionary.

It's also seen as "going by"

'Going off the age of the statues' seems to mean just what Brian Minton said.
If you prefer, 'working by/from/off/on…' try those and all should show the same meaning: basically, 'building on…'

Go off  in your context means:

(transitive) To follow or extrapolate from something; to judge by.

Usage examples:


Going off the interview alone, she seemed like the perfect employee.
8 October, 2020, Paul Oswell, Business Insider:
To see a room rate well under $200 is a rarity…. The occupancy rate during my stay seemed quite low, going off what I was able to see, with not many guests checking in or out and no crowds in the public spaces, and so social distancing wasn't an issue.


(Wiktionary)

“Going off” here is an informal way to say “judging from”.

or "deducing from".

or "based on", or "judging by"

For me, "going off" or "going from" can mean something deeper and subtler than simply "judging by". It's more intrinsic to the matter under discussion than an "external" observation of a situation, as in the OP's example, implied by "judging by".
In technical discourse, one can often translate "going off" as "using the definition X that" or "in the X-conception of" or even (although I've never seen it) "in the paradigm where". This is where there are several different notions or conceptions of related concept that overlap.
A simple "using", "by" or "through" would often suffice in such situations.
For example, in a subject beloved to me, differential geometry, there are several different conceptions of subtle concepts that characterize how surfaces and manifolds deviate from Euclidean geometry. In particular, there is a quite notoriously slippery notion of "torsion" that has an intuitive "twisting" meaning in the differential geometry of curves that doesn't really carry over to a more general definition in higher dimensions. So I might quite acceptably say:

"Going off" the notion afforded to us by the geometry of space curves in 3D space, the torsion simply measures the intuitive notion of the rate of twisting of the Frenet-Serret frame around the tangent vector to the space curve relative to the orthogonal pipe co-ordinate frame of [3], whereas, "going off/using" the covariant vector valued two form torsion definition, there can be nonzero torsion within a flat plane, even though there can be no nett twisting of the Frenet-Serret frame around the tangent for a space curve that remains in the plane."

I think you'd agree that "judging by" is completely inappropriate here, since there's no judging or estimating - it's how we are carefully choosing definitions to capture aspects of vague concepts and contrasting different conception of a notion - something we have to do in science all the time.
That being said, in more technical discussions "going from" is more usual than "going off". Moreover, it is unusual in technical discourse to use something as "colloquial" as these words, but the former is definitely seen from time to time, and, to me, in a dense and prickly concise technical discussion, it is perfectly acceptable and can be a welcome relief for the reader.
